# error Filters are deprecated how to solve this error in vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i'm trying to use filter in vue.js 3 to filter data into upper case but this error show when any filter?!! i tried lot of solutions but no way

main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./scss/main.scss";
import "normalize.css";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");

    new Vue({
        router,
        store,
        render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
    
    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
    
    Vue.filter('uppercase', function (v){
       return v.toUpperCase()
    });
```

component that i use filter:

```
<template>
    <div class="post-box">
        <span class="views">{{ views }}</span>
        <h3 class="title">{{title}}</h3>
        <span class="date">{{ date }}</span>
        <p class="content">{{ content }}</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 author">
            <span class="post-author">{{author | uppercase }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 category">
            <span class="post-category">{{category}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      props: ['title','content','author','category','date','views'],
      name: "BlogPost",
    };
    </script>
```

could u help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use a computed property instead of filters which are remove in vue 3 :
in main.js remove `import Vue from 'vue'` and :

```
new Vue({
        router,
        store,
        render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
    
    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
    
    Vue.filter('uppercase', function (v){
       return v.toUpperCase()
    });
```

In the child component define that property and use it inside the template as follows :

```
<template>
     ...
          <div class="col-sm-6 author">
            <span class="post-author">{{ uppercase(author) }}</span>
          </div>
     ...
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      props: ['title','content','author','category','date','views'],
      name: "BlogPost",
      computed:{
         uppercase(){
            return (v)=>{
              return v.toUpperCase()
              }
           }
     }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: when i remove  (import Vue from "vue";) and edit with computed, page says error    'Vue' is not defined

Comment: i shoud add (import Vue from "vue";) thanks it works now

Comment: In the main.js you're mixing the vue 2 and vue 3 syntax that leads to conflicts

Comment: Isn't it better to move `uppercase` in the `methods` section?

Comment: @DennyBiasiolli, it can work as a method but it's recommended to use computed property since it will be cached

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes, right ;) I was thinking of a "migration" from old filters to a widely used function, in the "methods" way a user can keep the "filter" function and importing in the required components